# How can I install skimage in Apple M1

Tags: python, apple-silicon

My python version is Python 3.9.7

I already install numpy

```
- Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.21.3)
```

I try to install skimage but it always errors

- some of error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-install-3q6bqogw/numpy_83bd11af3b6b4203acde5ac2725fbec9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-install-3q6bqogw/numpy_83bd11af3b6b4203acde5ac2725fbec9/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-record-z4tcrt34/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-build-env-plz5q6hb/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-build-env-plz5q6hb/overlay/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

```
########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
  Platform      :
    Architecture: aarch64
    Compiler    : clang
  
  CPU baseline  :
    Requested   : 'min'
    Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
    Flags       : none
    Extra checks: none
  
  CPU dispatch  :
    Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
    Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP
    Generated   : none
  CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[809] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/lz/tsh60j6j2tb1zp7q7ny8m4r40000gn/T/pip-install-cq9vfb32/scikit-image_1c9a815e92aa47ab95a3be9c605de958/build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
```